# Ho to change values for SOAPUI Request?

Tags: testing, soap, automation, automated-tests, soapui

Take values from Response Change into some String and save it.

> E.g. from req1 : Response : Company Name = Abc I Want to take this Name
>   from Response, Change to xyz and save it.

But every time I have to Change,  next time I will run then I will get xyz and this time I want to Change to some string and then save. Is it possible to do automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you're looking for, and it's not clear if your are using a XML response, json...

Supposing that you want to simply change a xml tag value in the response and set as a property to use it elsewhere, then you can for example do it adding a groovy script testStep below of your current request testStep.

If for example you have the follow response:

```
  <Response xmlns="sample">
    <CompanyName>Abc</CompanyName>
  </Response>
```

Then in the groovy script:

```
// get testStep by it's name
def testStep = context.testCase.getTestStepByName('SOAP Request 2')
// get the response
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(testStep.getPropertyValue('response'))
// update the companyName tag content
def node = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'CompanyName' }.each{ it.replaceBody('xyz') }
// save the response in a property
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('updatedResponse',groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize( xml ))
```

The script gets the response, update the value and then save it in a testCase property, to use it elsewhere directly in a request you can use the follow notation:

```
<soap:envelope ...>
   <soap:body>
      ${#TestCase#updatedResponse}
   </soap:body>
</soap:body>
```

Hope it helps,